# In c#, Struct can't inherit a class then why it is implicitly inheriting System.Object where System.Object is a class

Tags: c#

In c#, Struct can't inherit a class then why it is implicitly inheriting System.Object where System.Object is a class.

I know System.Object is the base type of every type. But since by definition , Struct can't inherit a class then why System.Object is inherit ?

Comment: The guys who write the compiler enforce the rules, so whatever they do IS within the rules by definition, because *force majeure*. Like the presidency, or Congress. Also, it's in the standard somewhere. There's always special cases.

Answer (score 4):

> But since by definition , Struct can't inherit a class

That's a false premise.  A custom struct *must* inherit directly from `System.ValueType`, which itself inherits from `System.Object`.  *That* is the requirement.  It cannot inherit from any **other** type.  So not only can a user defined struct inherit from a class, it in fact *must* inherit from [a specific] class.

(Note that enums must inherit from `Enum`, not `Object`, although `Enum` inherits from `ValueType`, which inherits from `Object`.)

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to say that `System.Object` is a contract that every `type` in `.NET` should follow. `Struct` instructs the compiler that the `type` is a `value type` and  `class` instructs the compiler that it is a `reference type`

Comment: AFAIK Structs **did not** inherit from anything. They are value types and when assigned to an Object variable they will be boxed. So this "inheritance" is just a look-alike done by internal magic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664476(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @LJ Your first sentence is a consequence of the fact that every type in C# must, directly or indirectly, inherit from `Object`.  The second sentence is true, but irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @SirRufo Every `type` inherits from `System.Object`; If you look at the `Rectangle` code, we can see that it is overriding `ToString` which is a `method` in `System.Object`; https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs

Comment: @SirRufo The fact that a value type needs to be boxed in order to be assigned to a reference in no way contradicts the fact that the type inherits from `Object`.  Both statements are true, and don't conflict.  Structs inherit from object, and also need to be (implicitly) boxed in order to be assigned to a variable of type `Object`.

Comment: @SirRufo What's  your point?  Note that that answer specifically states that structs inherit from `Object`.  It specifically contradicts *your* assertion that structs don't inherit from anything.

Comment: @Servy No, the answer states that value types did not inherit from anything. It is just compiler magic but not inheritance

Comment: @SirRufo "`A` derives from `System.ValueType` which in turn derives from `System.Object`"  You can also pull out the C# specs where it states the same thing.

Comment: Correct, all values types derive from `System.ValueType` which is turn is derived from `System.Object`

Comment: Ok, I may read the official docs in a different way than you. Never mind

Comment: @SirRufo Care to quote the specs where they say that user defined structs don't inherit from anything?

Comment: @SirRufo Since apparently you care about the spec's specific wording, from section 1.7, last sentence, first paragraph: "Struct types do not support user-specified inheritance, and all struct types implicitly inherit from type object."  So structs do in fact inherit from `object`.  It is stated as such explicitly.  (That's the C# 5.0 specs; it's what I had handy.)

Answer (score 1):

> In c#, Struct can't inherit a class

Yes, they cannot inherit from a `Custom class`, especially being a `Value type`, since they can only have operations allowed for the `Value types` like:

- Allocation on a simple data structure like `Stack`, unlike `Heap` for the reference types
- During a variable copy, being a `Value Type`, new allocation is made, as in case for primitive types, like `Integer`, `Float`, so `Struct s1 = s2`, creates a brand new copy, but for reference type, it is copy of Reference, which means pointer to same memory

> Main point, then why allow to derive from `System.Object` class, multiple important reasons:

- Created CTS (Common / unified Type System), where ultimately type converges to base class `System.Object` and can thus be represented in a unified manner
- `Value types` are still primitive in operation and capability as compared to `Reference types` and has limitation of what they can represent, that's a why a base type is reference type, so that when the need be, conversion can be done via boxing, do allocation on heap and use the functionalities of a reference type
- Allow certain basic common functions exposed by `System.Object` on all the types, value and reference like `ReferenceEquals, GetHashCode, MemberwiseClone,ToString,GetType`, though certainly post overriding